# Ruby On Rails Devise Install Problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I apologise if my question is too simple, but I'm new to ruby. I'm trying to add  authentication to my rails project using devise application. 
After going through all steps that are described in this tutorial:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/209-introducing-devise?autoplay=true

I do not get devise.rb file (btw installation is successfull, I see warden and devise in bundler installation list) and everything goes wrong, because after user model creation  migration finishes with error message: devise method is unrecognised.

Maybe You could give me some advice why this is happening? 
I'm working on Windows.

Thanks for Your response.

Answer (score 0):

Upload your code on github (without passswords) because I don't know where you do mistakes. 
Did you run this "rails generate devise_install" without errors? Do you tried create manualy devise.rb file?

Comment: Thank, You, quatermain, for attention.  The thing is that all codes I took from these tutorial - http://railscasts.com/episodes/209-introducing-devise  
I've run 'rails new devise_install' in cmd and it seems that everything was correct. 
I haven't created devise.rb file because not sure what should be in it. As I read in all posts devise.rb should be created automatically after installation.   
The last my attempt was to delete Gemfile.lock but it didn't help also...

Comment: First, your app name is not good. Good names for example: blog, portal, FirmName,blogchat, blogdevise... not funcion. 
for example: rails g new blogdevise, edit Gemfile, add "gem 'devise'". Run bundle in root directory(..../blogdevise/bundle). And now "rails generate devise_install". You must have some model for login, for example user, so "rails g scaffold User name email",run migration "rake db:migrate". Run "rails generate devise User". Do this with new project, in new folder. Very simple.

Comment: I meant that command 'generate' doesn't work in cmd, works only 'rails new', with project name everything is okay it's simply "CardStore"... and I already have user model. So then I should conclude that I can't run normally 'rails generate devise:install'. But I see the devise in the gem list...Just don't get what to do.

Comment: Yes, just every time I'm trying to run 'rails generate' command, cmd answers me that the usage is 'rails new APP_PATH'. 
Could You please help me with that.

Comment: Are you in app root folder? Try:"gem update --system" to update your gems. Do you must use windows?:D Windows has some problem with your RoR maybe. Reinstall everything, maybe help

Comment: Thank God that was not necessary :D I found solution, but I can't explain You how -  it was a miracle :D Thanks for helping!